# Why is interface merging not working in this case?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm writing some WebGL code in Visual Studio Code (with type declarations coming from npm package @types/webgl2) and typescript doesn't seem to be merging the following interface.

```
interface WebGL2RenderingContext {
    myExtension(): void
}

const gl: WebGL2RenderingContext = canvasElem.getContext("webgl2")
gl.myExtension() //getting a TS error saying 'myExtension' does not exist on type WebGL2RenderingContext
```

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

**EDIT:** So I probably should have included `extends WebGLRenderingContext`, as this is how the interface of `WebGL2RenderingContext` is defined. However, it still does not work as I was expecting.

```
interface WebGL2RenderingContext extends WebGLRenderingContext {
    myExtension(): void
}

const gl: WebGL2RenderingContext = canvasElem.getContext("webgl2")
gl.myExtension() //works
gl.createTexture() //works
gl.createVertexArray() //getting a TS error saying 'createVertexArray' does not exist on type WebGL2RenderingContext

//note: createTexture is present in WebGLRenderingContext while createVertexArray is only present in WebGL2RenderingContext
```

Comment: I think we need more of your code to diagnose this.  How are you importing `WebGL2RenderingContext` in the first place?  Have you read about [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer at the bottom of the page [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) (thanks jcalz) where it talks about "global augmentation".

```
declare global {
    interface WebGL2RenderingContext extends WebGLRenderingContext {
        myExtensionMethod(): void
    }
}

WebGL2RenderingContext.prototype.myExtensionMethod = function() {
    // todo: implement myExtensionMethod
}

export default {} //makes this a module
```