# Property does not exist when extending Date type

Tags: typescript, typeerror, nodemon

I have extended the built in Date type with a `addDays` property:

```
\\src\extensions\date.extension.ts
interface Date {
  addDays: (days: number) => Date;
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function (days: number) {
  let date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
};
```

I have then tried using it in this function:

```
\\src\statArrayClass.ts
...
let currentDate: Date = startDate;
      while (currentDate <= endDate) {
        daysWithData.push({ date: currentDate, data: false });
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
      }
...
```

When I try to build this, I get a tserror `Property 'addDays' does not exist on type 'Date'`

This seems to only error when building using nodemon.

How could I build this without the error.

Comment: Did you use [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) to put the merged `Date` interface into the global scope?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035887/why-is-interface-merging-not-working-in-this-case

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the suggestion, have tried using those steps, but seem to get the same error when running `nodemon`

Comment: Hmm, then I'm not sure what to say, unless you can link to a web IDE project that displays this behavior.   Of course, someone else more familiar with nodemon might not require a [mcve] to answer.  Good luck!